# What is the alternative of view.x and view.y in android jetpack compose...?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I wants to get coordinates of a view in jetpack compose like we get in android by using following code...i.e view.x and view.y that gives you x and y coordinates how we can achieve this in jetpack compose....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Modifier`'s `onGloballyPositioned` method and retrieve its coordinates (from its parent or the root screen) from the `layoutParameter` passed down in the lambda

Comment: I have tried this and compare values get from both function like values get from view.x is differen from values get from onGloballyPositioned changed...i tested both on same device

Comment: @AliJawadHussainGorayya post your code

Comment: i tink there is no need of code posting